How do you get rid of these labels that VS code sets on my code?
These label thingies make it so hard to code:
screenshot
I googled how to turn them off and I turned off all suggestions, but it still won't work :( I don't think that these are suggestions but I have no idea what they would be called.

If You use C# with extension then go to Settings -> Extensions -> C# -> Text Editor -> turn off: InlayHints: Enable Inlay Hints For Implicit Variable Types.
settings menu screenshot
